# How to get back a context sensitive ribbon in the CRM 2013 dashboard

Tags: customization, dynamics-crm-2013

In the CRM 2011 dashboard, the ribbon changed regarding to the selected object.
So for example if you selected an active queue item there appeared: Routing, Work on, etc...

This is the behavior we'd like to get back in the new version, as it's usability right now is just horrible..

If you open the list in a separate window, all the options are there, so why can't we get them directly in the dashboard?

We tried the following:

- Basically copy/paste the original routing button from the queue item
  site to the dashboard. Button showed up, but just does nothing.
- Displaying an iframe on the dashboard which source is the address of
  the queue item site. This worked for some seconds, then it
  first showed a duplicate of the dashboard in the iframe and after
  that the iframe simply contained some blank html.

That's when we decided to ask this question ;)

Any hints would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I've already tried to adopt the "Route To" Button from the QueueItem-View to the dashboard (or at least to an incident's form, so its queueitem can be routed to somebody) with no luck :-(
CRM2013's UI seems to be a big step in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit late to the party but thought i'd add my input.

I faced the same problem as we had a dashboard which had multiple sub grids and depending on which grid you were in enabled / disabled certain ribbon buttons to facilitate a process through varying statuses.

Like you, when upgrading to 2013, we found out that the contextual sub grid ribbon has become no more. As far as I could tell, there was no way to get this back nor a graceful way around the problem.

Things that I tried included:

- Making a change to the actual Dashboard command bar which is available on all dashboards, then adding enable / display rules to control when the buttons were displayed. This for me didn't prove successful but depending on what you are trying to do may be viable.
- As you've discovered, Clicking the button to the right of the grid opens it in an associated view which gives you back the functionality you want. But is annoying from a usability point of view as you have to open a new window, find a record if it's record specific then click your button, so again i ruled this one out.
- In the end, I modified the sitemap to create a new sub area for the collection of entities I was using, So it replicates the associated view, and is driven from entity views rather than from a sub grid. Not ideal, but the behaviour we used is gone.

The reason i believe this behaviour is gone is due to the ethos of "removing complexity of the ribbon" starting with only showing 5 buttons. So the idea of the ribbon changing based on a click of the user was deemed "confusing".

For me, this removes some of the functionality and purpose of a dashboard. If you found a different workaround I'd love to hear it but I ended up re-working my ui.